# Laravel error Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel

I have read other questions in this forum to fix this problem, but nothing helped me.

I'm receiving this error only in one folder in other folder laravel works perfect no errors.
Error is:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

The code i using.
homa.blade.php

```
<section>
    <h2><a href="{{ URL::action('post-show', $post->slug) }}">{{ $post->title }}</a></h2>
    {{ Markdown::parse(Str::limit($post->body, 300)) }}
    <a href="{{ URL::action('post-show', $post->slug) }}">Read more &rarr;</a>
</section>
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/posts/{$slug}', array(
    'as' => 'post-show',
    'uses' => 'PostController@getShow'
));
```

and controller is PostController.php

```
<?php

class PostController extends BaseController {

    public function getShow($slug) {
        echo 'Tets';
    }
}
```

This is all my code nothing more.

Comment: Is your `homa.blade.php` the view you get from a subfolder, and not root `yourwebsite.com/`?

Comment: to `youwebsite.com` is rooting but to `youwebsite.com/posts/topic-name-here` got error

Comment: So the url you got from `<a href="...">` is correct, but going to that url causes the problem right? Or is it wrong from the url produced?

Comment: problem was in route I'm used `Route::get('/posts/{$slug}')` with `$` i should use without. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you should use (Remove `$` from `{$slug}`):

```
Route::get('/posts/{slug}', array(
    'as' => 'post-show',
    'uses' => 'PostController@getShow'
));
```

Also change:

```
<a href="{{ URL::action('post-show', $post->slug) }}">Read more &rarr;</a>
```

To this:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('post-show', $post->slug) }}">Read more &rarr;</a>
```

Or use `route` helper function:

```
<a href="{{ route('post-show', $post->slug) }}">Read more &rarr;</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`URL::action` (as the name implies) expects an action, not a route name as you're passing.

> public string action(string $action, mixed $parameters = array(), bool
>   $absolute = true)

You should use route():

```
URL::route('post-show', array($post->slug))
```

> public string route(string $name, mixed $parameters = array(), bool
>   $absolute = true, Route $route = null)

Comment: I agree. In addition to that, I'm not sure but this `Route::get('/posts/{$slug}'...)` might also be causing a problem, does it work with the $ sign?

Comment: still not working, in previous project for me worked with `URL::action()` too.

Comment: Uhm, I never checked that, but I guess it's treated as a string

Comment: holly crap, from where i dreamed that `Route::get('/posts/{$slug}')` need to use with $... thanks that was a problem.